# Redirect subsite to another subsite URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have (for example) site help.test.pl

I would like redicrect from subsite `help.test.pl/site1` to another URL of this site: `help.test.pl/site1/info/sport`

If I do in apache:

```
Redirect 301 /site1 https://help.test.pl/site1/info/sport
```

and If i run site `help.test.pl/site1` in my browser the  "`info/sport/`" of URL is looped.

The URL look like:

```
https://help.test.pl/site1/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport/info/sport
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect folder to another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174098/htaccess-redirect-folder-to-another-folder)

Comment: Its not this problem. Without change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one method from below  :

**1)  Using `RewriteRule`.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /site1$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://help.test.pl/site1/info/sport [R=301,L]
```

**2) Using `RedirectMatch`**

```
RedirectMatch 301 /site1$ https://help.test.pl/site1/info/sport
```

**EDIT:** add another page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /site1$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /site2$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://help.test.pl/$1/info/sport [R=301,L]
```

Comment: First work! Thx :) I have only one question. Can I Use in RewriteCond two sitetes (parametres)?
for example /site1$ or /site2$ ??

Comment: @Ebasse yes you can, please check my updated answer.